# Audio Not Playing In Unity Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was coding a script in unity and then I tried to make it so that makes it so audio plays 2 seconds after another audio is played. I did this by making the script wait 2 more seconds than the audio length of the audio clip before it. I used PlayOneShot to play audio. There were no errors in the script but still the audio was not played I did drag it in with the inspector.

Here's my code:

(Didn't let me paste code in so just using image)

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4znw.png)

Here's proof that the audio is put in the inspector:

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUc6l.png)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the code seems quite straight-forward and should play as expected. Can you please confirm that you haven't inadvertently muted the Unity inspector? You can check by looking [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26JQ7.png)

Comment: It's not off and the previous sound that plays because it plays when the scene is loaded and that previous audio still played so I am confused

Comment: I FIXED IT ON MY OWN I just had to do a very small tweak to the code and it worked

Comment: Make sure the code actually works before suggesting it does and there might another issue.